# DDT on Eclipse Juno

Tags: ide, version, d, eclipse-juno

Has anybody made DDT (D Development Tools) to work on Eclipse Juno? When I try to install DDT it complains about wrong version of the DLTK.

**Update**: Since DDT verion 0.8 Eclipse Kepler and DLTK 5.0 is supported by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to install an old dltk version until DDT author ports it to new one.

Relevant comments: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/ddt/wiki/Installation

Quoting Bruno:

```
The http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo update site contains DLTK 3.0, 
so the installation should still work as described above. There might be a problem if 
Eclipse update actually finds DLTK 3.0 but also finds 4.0 and is trying to install 4.0 if
some other plugin requires version 4.0. Make sure Eclipse is not trying to get updated
to 4.0 .
```